# Present simple or present continuous - I'm on the bus

Tags: present-tense

Present simple or present continuous? What tense are the following sentences? " I have a headache","he is on the bus",she is at work",he is tired",she is at the shop","I feel good".All these sentences describes something what is happening right now, so would it be present continious?

Comment: They're present simple with *linking verbs* or *stative verbs*.

Comment: Any progressive aspect is usually indicated with an 'ing' form of the verb fronted with some construction  of 'be'...consider asking questions like this on [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)